# SSL Client Authentication with Google Cloud Run

Tags: express, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to move an existing backend over to Google Cloud Run. Some of the endpoints (under a specific subdomain) require SSL Client Authentication. The way this is handled at the moment is on Nginx configuration level:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name secure.subdomain.example.com;
    [...]

    # SSL Client Certificate:
    ssl_client_certificate xxx.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    [...]

    location / {
        if ($ssl_client_verify != "SUCCESS") { return 403 $ssl_client_verify; }
        [...]
    }
}
```

What would be the best approach to handle SSL client certificate authentication with Google Cloud Run? I assume this would need some sort of load balancer on the correct network layer and with support for cloud run?

Of course there is always the option to authenticate in the ExpressJS app, but if possible I would prefer it to happen before even reaching Cloud Run.

Answer (score 3):

You can't achieve that with Cloud Run. The SSL connection is terminated at the load balancer side (On an HTTPS load balancer, or on the Cloud Run built-in load balancer). You only receive HTTP traffic to your service.

Indeed, you can add additional security information, in the request header, but you lost the SSL flavor.

Comment: How could Google leave out something so essential?

Comment: It's the design!! Use @JohnHanley answer if you want to have SSL mutual auth.

Answer (score 3):

[**UPDATE 05-12-2023**]

My answer is no longer current. Review these Google documents:

- [Set up mutual TLS with user-provided certificates](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-mtls-ccm)
- [Set up mutual TLS for a global external HTTP(S) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-mtls-global-ext-https)

[**END UPDATE**]

> What would be the best approach to handle SSL client certificate
> authentication with Google Cloud Run?

Cloud Run does not support SSL Client Certificate Authentication. The GFE (Google Front End) proxies requests for Cloud Run applications and does not pass-through requests. The only Google Cloud load balancers that support SSL client certificates are based on Google Maglev.

None of the Google Cloud managed **compute** services support SSL client certificate authentication (mutual TLS authentication).

Consider using Compute Engine instead of Cloud Run.Then configure Nginx to handle client authentication. For load balancing, use a pass-through load balancer such as [External TCP/UDP Network Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/network)

Comment: Thank you! The pass-through load balancer would not allow me to implement mTLS, it would only be in interplay with Compute Engine and the correct Nginx configuration, correct?

Comment: @ManfredLinzner - If you need load balancing, a pass-through load balancer would allow your backend to support mTLS. A pass-through load balancer does not proxy (SSL terminate), your backend (Compute Engine + Nginx) would then support mTLS. The point that I was making was that there are two types of Google load balancers - proxy and pass-through. Select a pass-through load balancer if you also need that feature.

Comment: This is an utterly confounding level of negligence on Google's part.  HTTPS is used on all levels nowadays.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle - What negligence are you referring to? Google supports HTTPS everywhere. Offloading SSL is very common. mTLS is still rare today except in large enterprises. Please clarify your comment.

Comment: @JohnHanley The negligence I'm speaking of comes with having to add an otherwise redundant and uselss endpoint on top of what is advertised as infrastructure as a service fully managed by Google. Even in this documentation it claims SSL is part of this. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/overview/what-is-cloud-run

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle - Please be specific. What redundant and useless endpoint are you referring to?